# Flask session example fails with WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file

Tags: session, flask

I am trying to learn session management in Flask to be be able to build a login screen. 
I tried following example code list at http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/86/.
and getting following error.

```
WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\\Users\\MYUSERID\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Flask_sessions\\09e12992-2938-44eb-a527-52fa22ce1983'
```

This happens in demo code where os.unlink(session.path) is called. 
I am running this example on Windows and think windows is locking the file. 
Can someone suggest how I can adopt this sample code for windows please?

Code Snippet:
view init method:
    app.session_interface = SqliteSessionInterface(path)
    mySession = app.session_interface.open_session(app,request)

Comment: I am calling open_session by passing app and request object in init of my View class. which in-turn calls save_session. I am not sure why save session should attempt to remove the file?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/iIJ0Jo0.png?1

Answer (score 0):

You're having a privilege error there, probably because you're not running the code on the highest privilege does not allow you to run **os.unlink** without getting that error. You should try running it as administrator or grant your user full privilege to the folder where you're storing your sessions.

Comment: Or even better as a user (or a user within a group) that has write privileges to the folder.

Comment: @Leandro Poble  I checked the permission on the folder they look right and I am able to create and delete files from same windows ID. ( pls note this is on Windows 7 ) . I can see that Files are locked by python process.

Comment: @Harish Could you add a screenshot of the rights you own on the folder? This has happened to me on Windows and it was always either a permission error or the file I was writing wasn't closed (for text files, obviously).

Comment: my reputation does not allow me to post images :-0)

Comment: @Harish upload it to imgur and add it on your post, then.